# real-time motion planning in moveit

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, motion-planners

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My question is about real-time motion planning in moveit or other ros packages. currently there are a good number of offline planners in moveit but is there any online and real-time planning method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318491/real-time-motion-planning-in-moveit/) by [hooman](https://answers.ros.org/users/39987/hooman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-03-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bottlesong](https://answers.ros.org/users/42924/bottlesong/) on 2019-06-28**:
I'm searching for a similar package too. I want to implement a real-time obstacles avoidance planning using ROS. Have you found any suitable solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am pretty sure the short answer is "No", it is not made for high-speed servoing etc, but you could use its parts to make something that might suit your needs. The harder your real-time requirements and the more you need trajectories updated on-the-fly, the less likely it is that you will have an easy time.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2019-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hooman](https://answers.ros.org/users/39987/hooman/) on 2019-03-19**:
thanks,I have also been using it more for offline planning giving the optimization enough time to find good plans. Are there other packages that can do real-time planning under constraint?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-03-19**:
I don't know of any. If offline planning is fine, implementing a method in MoveIt might be the most convenient option.